# How to get an object as a string in innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

So I'm targeting my svg and its surrounding div:

```
const svg = e.target.parentElement;
```

Then I have `${svg}` in the following context:

```html
result.innerHTML = <h1 class="text-win">You won</h1> <div class="result"> ${svg} </div>
```

But I always get `${svg}` as `[object HTMLDivElement]`. How would I get the `svg` to display as a string instead of an object?

Comment: Use .`outerHTML` on the svg variable.

Comment: `${svg.outerHTML}`

Comment: And putting it into `result.innerHTML`…? Do you just want to move or copy the SVG? Because that’d be `result.appendChild(svg)` or `result.appendChild(svg.cloneNode(true))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`parentElement`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp) is an *HTML DOM Element **Object***.

When you inject it using the `${svg}`, you actually call its `toString()` method, which returns the string `[object HTMLDivElement]`.

As suggested, if you'll use the [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Value) property of `svg`, you'll get the result you're expecting:

> Reading the value of `outerHTML` returns a `DOMString` containing an HTML serialization of the element and its descendants